# Does the pressure caused by the force exerted on an ideal fluid in a Bernoulli tube decrease over an increasing distance?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, bernoulli-equation

Does the pressure caused by the force exerted on an ideal fluid in a Bernoulli tube decrease over an increasing distance?
For example, someone pushes the water with a force from the left in this setup.

[image: Bernoulli experiment]

Comment: Why is this tagged with superfluidity?

Comment: [Similar on hold post by OP](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/464669/bernoulli-experiment-why-is-the-pressure-on-the-left-greater)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a duplicate of https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/464669/bernoulli-experiment-why-is-the-pressure-on-the-left-greater

Comment: I'm assuming $P_1$ is the pressure resulting from the force being applied by our "someone". What is $P_2$?

Comment: @Gert I don't think it's a duplicate. At least not yet... It's just not a clear question still

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bernoulli Experiment- why is the pressure on the left greater?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/464669/bernoulli-experiment-why-is-the-pressure-on-the-left-greater)